# Customize DataGrid Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a **ListBox** in **ColumnHeaderStyle** of a **DataGrid**.

[image]

What is the best solution to **bind** the **distinct list** of all rows values for each column to this ListBox?

Comment: Hi, do you bind to a collection of regular CLR objects?

Comment: I bind Xml data using XmlDataProvider.But the Q is general.

Comment: you see WPF bindgind do depend on a data type, they even have different members for objects and Xml - path & XPath. You best bet would be to use attached behaviors, which will rely on a your data types, unless you use some sort of expandos.

Comment: there's a simple solution if you're happy to sacr paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind it to your ItemsSource, using a converter with a parameter, it should be dead simple (use `RelativeSource` for navigating to `ItemsSource`, then use `LINQ` `Distinct` ior its `XLINQ` analog). That is simple , data source type specific way (non-generic).

What you could try as well is `CollectionViewSource` and `PropertyGroupDescription`. Your header can be thought of a headers-only control for displaying grouped data, can't it? You can take a sample of grouping data and remove `<ItemsPresenter/>` from your `GroupItem`'s template.

If it's too vague just shout I'll create s sample.